# getSupportLoaderManager() deprecated

Tags: android

В версии API 28 и выше `Loader-ы` объявили устаревшими ведь, а рекомендуют вместо них использовать связку `LiveData` и `ViewModel`.

В связи с этим у меня вопросы. Для начала у меня есть две таблицы в БД, которые используются в приложении словарь. В зависимости от переключателя выводятся данные из одной или второй таблицы.

Таблицы: `TABLE_RUSOTHER` и `TABLE_OTHERRUS`.

Хотела бы узнать для каждой таблицы нужно создавать свой `ViewModel` и как вообще класс `ViewModel` реализовать? По моему коду как мне дальше действовать? На startandroid есть уроки по ViewModel, но по ней поняла только поверхностно что и для чего это.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, WordsAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    RecyclerView rvList;

    private TextView txtLeftLang;
    private TextView txtRightLang;
    private ImageButton btnReverseLang;
    private boolean isOtherRight; //При запуске приложения False

    DBHelper db;

    private int currentLoader;
    final private static int LOADER_RUS = 0;
    final private static int LOADER_OTHER = 1;

    WordsAdapter wordsAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        txtLeftLang = findViewById(R.id.txtLeftLang);
        txtRightLang = findViewById(R.id.txtRightLang);
        btnReverseLang = findViewById(R.id.btnReverseLang);

        txtLeftLang.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.rus_lang));
        txtRightLang.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.other_lang));

        db = new DBHelper(this);

        rvList = findViewById(R.id.rvList);
        rvList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        wordsAdapter = new WordsAdapter(this);
        rvList.setAdapter(wordsAdapter);
        wordsAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle(1);
        bundle.putString("filter", "");

        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_OTHER, bundle, this);
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_RUS, bundle, this); //Этот загрузчик будет отображаться в списке при запуске приложения

        btnReverseLang.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                txtRightLang.setText(isOtherRight? getResources().getString(R.string.other_lang):getResources().getString(R.string.rus_lang));
                txtLeftLang.setText(isOtherRight? getResources().getString(R.string.rus_lang):getResources().getString(R.string.other_lang));

                if (isOtherRight) { //перевод с русского на другой
                    currentLoader = LOADER_RUS;
                } else { // перевод с другого на русский
                    currentLoader = LOADER_OTHER;
                }

                getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(currentLoader).forceLoad(); //загружаем нужный список в зависимости от переключателя языков
                isOtherRight = !isOtherRight;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Word.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", id);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFavoriteButtonClick(long id, boolean isFavorite) {
        String table;
        String fav;
        String toast;
        int currentLoader;

        if (isOtherRight) {
            table = DBContract.Entry.TABLE_OTHERRUS;
            currentLoader = LOADER_OTHER;

        } else {
            table = DBContract.Entry.TABLE_RUSOTHER;
            currentLoader = LOADER_RUS;
        }

        if (isFavorite) {
            fav = "0";
            toast = "Удалено из избранного";
        } else {
            fav = "1";
            toast = "Добавлено в избранное";
        }

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DBContract.Entry.COLUMN_FAVORITES, fav);
        long newRowId = db.myDataBase.update(table, values, DBContract.Entry._ID + "= " + id, null);
        if (newRowId == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(currentLoader).forceLoad();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bundle) {
        String filter = bundle.getString("filter");
        return new MyCursorLoader(this, db, id, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        wordsAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        wordsAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

    static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {
        Cursor cursor;
        DBHelper dbHeler;
        final int loaderID;
        String filter;

        public MyCursorLoader(Context context, DBHelper dbHeler, int id, String filter) {
            super(context);
            this.dbHeler = dbHeler;
            loaderID = id;
            this.filter = filter;
        }

        @Override
        protected Cursor onLoadInBackground() {
            switch (loaderID) {
                case LOADER_RUS:
                    cursor = dbHeler.getRusWords(filter);
                    break;
                case LOADER_OTHER:
                    cursor = dbHeler.getOtherWords(filter);
                    break;
            }
            return cursor;
        }
    }

    private void refreshCursor(String str) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle(1);
        bundle.putString("filter", str);
        getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(currentLoader, bundle, this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
        MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(search);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                wordsAdapter.setFilterLength(newText.length());
                refreshCursor(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Здравствуйте! Почитайте вот это: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide. Знаю на Английском сложно, но тут всё есть.

Comment: Изучите `Room`: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room с примерами в `codelabs`, оно того стоит, т.к. Ваш класс `MainActivity` не будет так разбухнут, и все будет по полочкам. Прежде чем осуществлять переход, изучите как мигрировать свои данные и стэк `LiveData` с `ViewModel`. Достаточно одного `ViewModel` с методами для разных таблиц, аля `get, insert, delete, update`.

Comment: Room я знаю в основном. Писала приложения используя его. Но на Room немного сложновато для меня. Для каждой таблицы нужно писать свой адаптер. Но никогда не использовала Room в связке с ViewModel

Comment: Я чет даже представить не могу `Room` без `ViewModel`… Посмотрите простенький пример: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#8 Все подробно и понятно даже если через гугл транслит :) Для каждой таблицы с данными своя сущность, для каждой сущности свой `DAO`, а для всего этого дела один репозиторий и `ViewModel` c методами, ну и собственно сам коннект к бд. А в классе подписывайтесь на `ViewModel` и обновляйте `UI`.

Comment: Пример по ссылке https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#15 поняла. Я в принципе с Room работала примерно также, но не использовала ViewModel. По другому немного делала. У меня вопрос такой. Для каждой из двух таблиц мне нужно делать свой класс ViewModel и репозиторий или одного достаточно?

Comment: Вам нужно сделать один класс репозитория (или вообще не делать его в вашем случае) и один класс ViewModel, в которых реализовать методы для работы с двумя таблицами. Я вообще без класса репозитория делал, то есть ViewModel через DAO напрямую обращалась к Room (по типу, как в уроках startandroid сделано). Вообще, репозиторий нужен только в случае смешанных источников данных, напр. локальная БД и сервер в сети, что прямо сказано в первых строках на том же CodeLabs

Comment: Не бойтесь применять `ViewModel`! Он сделан для того, чтобы Вам же жилось легче. С ним не надо парится о поворотах экрана :)

Comment: Поняла. Попробую начать. Если что буду писать вопросы)

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно реализовать один класс `ViewModel` для работы со всеми таблицами из своей БД. В самом классе нужно реализовать отдельные методы для всех операций, которые вам потребуются совершать с базой данных (так же эти операции должны быть реализованы в реализации DAO, если речь идет о использовании Room в качестве БД) - например, получение всех данных по имени таблицы, получение отфильтрованных данных (как только избранное), запись в таблицу, удаление и тд.

Примерный вид класса `ViewModel` может быть таким:

```
public class WordsViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private AppDataBase appDataBase;

    public WordsViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        appDataBase = AppDataBase.getInstance(application.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public LiveData<List<Word>> getAllWords(String table){
        return appDataBase.wordsDao().getAll(table);
    }

    public Word getById(long id){
        return appDatabase.wordsDao().getByID(id);
    }

    ....
}
```

где `Word` - модель для Room одного элемента таблицы

DAO:

```
@Dao
interface WordsDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM :table")
    LiveData<List<Word>> getAll(String table);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM TABLE_RUSOTHER WHERE id = :id")
    Word getByID(long id);

    ....
}
```

ну и использовать так:

Получить все записи из таблицы TABLE_RUSOTHER:

```
wordsViewModel.getAllWords("TABLE_RUSOTHER");
```

Comment: Я извиняюсь, начала делать пока что более менее все понятно. Но не понятно как создать адаптер для обеих таблиц? Тут https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#10 описан адаптер, но пример для одной таблицы там, а у меня две таблицы и адаптер ничем не будет отличаться для обеих. Меняется только название таблицы и содержимое, а структура одна и та же.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать одну таблицу, создать столбец OTHER, для TABLE_RUSOTHER значение 0, для TABLE_RUSOTHERRUS - 1, загружать данные

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM :table WHERE OTHER = 0")
LiveData<List<Word>> getAll(String table);
```

или

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM :table WHERE OTHER = 1")
    LiveData<List<Word>> getAll(String table);
```